# Constant current and constant voltage control of inverter

Tags: power, power-electronics, power-engineering

Most of inverters in the grid are based on constant current control where inner current control loop tries to limit the current. Hence acting as a constant current source. I was wondering how control philosophy will be difference if we were to model the same inverter as a constant voltage source?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the inverters on the grid are based on energy storage in an inductance, either in a discrete inductor, or the inductance of a transformer.

The purpose of the outer loop is to control the flow of power to the load. The purpose of the inner loop is to control the cycle by cycle energy contained in the energy storage element.

This means the natural thing to do is to control the current.

Comment: How does a inverter in microgrid is modeled then...if outer control is regulating power?

Comment: The outer loop is asked to deliver a certain amount of power to the grid. This might be  fixed value, it might come from MPPT, it might be from a measurement or an estimate of what the prime source can deliver, and it must be less or equal to what the prime source can deliver. The inner current loop then controls the cycle by cycle energy storage to deliver that power, while meeting other requirements like limiting peak current, controlling the power factor etc.

Comment: @johndaniel The above is so self-evident that it sounds like your conceptual problem is elsewhere